# Forcing <li>'s width to be the same as it's content

Tags: jquery, css

I got an unordered list (UL) which obviously contains list items (li).

The problem with that is, the **li** tag width is the same as it's parent width. I havent assigned a width to the **ul** tag, but I have assigned a width to the **DIV** which contains the **UL**. The width that i've assigned is 600px, therefore, my **li** tags are now 600width, doesnt matter if it has only 2 words in it.

How do I make the li be the same width as it's content?

Thanks!

Comment: placing a demo would be good consider.

Comment: place a link http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: did you see another demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want like this? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yfPjm/)

css

```
div{width: 600px; background-color: gray;}
ul{list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
li{background-color: red; display: table-row;}
```

html

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>list 1</li>
        <li>list 2</li>
        <li>list three 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can also do as this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yfPjm/1/)

```
li{background-color: red; width: auto; display: table;}
```

I've alos found out another method. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5bQP/6/)

```
ul{background-color: gray; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
li{background-color: red; display: inline-block; width:100%;}
```

Comment: exactly!
Just a question, the table-row display method, does it support all of the browsers?

Answer (score 4):

By default `div`, `ul` & `li` are all `display:block` meaning `width:100%`. To make them shrink to their content they would need to be inline-block, use this class on them to achieve this..

```
.inline_block{
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

EDIT: Found a better way of doing it.

```
li{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LhzWe/

Comment: but that's creating another problem, now the **li** elements are near eachother and not in one above the other. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: doesn't work, just added the: *clear:both* statement, didn't change anything

Comment: @kfirba please see my edit. A 100% browser friendly solution.